# Quick OSM is giving bad request

Tags: qgis, openstreetmap, quickosm

I used Quick OSM a few weeks ago, in QGIS, but now every time I run a quick Query I get `Bad request Overpass API`, even on the project it was working on previously. I have tried all different Keys, values, and extents, I have recently updated the plugin.

Am I missing something?

Answer (score 5):

Try different "Parameters" options for "Overpass API" and "Nominatim API".

[image]

Before:

[image]

After:

[image]